# ReferenceError : By is not defined - webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

**Code :**

```
var assert = require('assert');
describe('webdriver.io api page', function() {
    it('should open login page', function () {
        browser.url('/login');
        browser.pause(10000);
})

it('Should enter login details and submit', function() {

    browser.pause(10000);
    browser.element(By.xpath("//input[@type='text' and @aria-label='user name']")).sendKeys("mikestr");

})
});
```

I am new to webdriverIO and trying to locate username textbox using xpath but it throws me error. I look around many webdriverIO material but did not get solution for this yet.

Comment: Can you post the error it throws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebdriverIO's Selectors are different than Selenium Webdriver. It will accept the String value for either "XPath" or "CSS" selectors. The "By is not defined" Error you're seeing is because it's looking for a "String" value of a selector.

Documentation:
http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#CSS-Query-Selector

In your situation you would only need to pass something like:

```
browser.element('"//input[@type='text' and @aria-label='user name']"')
       .setValue('mikestr')
```

Alternatively you could set the variable and pass a variable like:

```
var XPath = "//input[@type='text' and @aria-label='user name']"
browser.element(XPath).setValue('mikestr')
```

Answer (score 1):

The locator has to be a string

For setting value , you can use [setValue](http://webdriver.io/api/action/setValue.html)

```
browser.setValue("//input[@type='text' and @aria-label='user name']", 'mikestr');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue using angular with the same `By is not defined` error. For anyone else that might end up here the solution for me was to add the import

```
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```